# Separate values ​by commas and add a column indicating the order of those values

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a column with values ​​separated by commas, I'm looking to separate them and create a row for each value group by store and region. Then create a column indicating the order each value was in:

Input:

| Store | Region | Product_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1C,18 |
| 1 | B | 6,B6 |
| 2 | A | 20,A9 |
| 2 | C | L0 |

Output:

| Store | Region | Product_ID | SPLIT | ORDER_SPLIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1C,18 | 1C | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1C,18 | 18 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 6,B6 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 6,B6 | B6 | 2 |
| 2 | A | 20,A9 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 20,A9 | A9 | 2 |
| 2 | C | L0 | L0 | 1 |

I managed to separate the columns, using:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode

SELECT *, explode(split(Product_ID, ',')) AS SPLIT
FROM _mytable_ GROUP BY store, region
```

While it seems to sort them in order, I didn't find anything indicating that the explode function would split them in order for me (so I could then create a rank, relying on the order returned).

If anyone can assure me that it will always split in order, or know any other function/way that will serve the purpose to help me create the "order_split" column, I would appreciate it.

I'm on databricks and in this case use pyspark.sql.

Thanks

Comment: why do you want split order  and in new row ? can you please complete logic what are you going to do after split ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `posexplode` function.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.select("*",posexplode(split(col("product_id"),",")).alias('ORDER_SPLIT','SPLIT')).\
  withColumn("ORDER_SPLIT",col("ORDER_SPLIT")+1).\
    show()
#+-----+------+----------+-----------+-----+
#|store|region|product_id|ORDER_SPLIT|SPLIT|
#+-----+------+----------+-----------+-----+
#|    1|     A|     1c,18|          1|   1c|
#|    1|     A|     1c,18|          2|   18|
#|    1|     B|      6,B6|          1|    6|
#|    1|     B|      6,B6|          2|   B6|
#|    2|     C|        L0|          1|   L0|
#+-----+------+----------+-----------+-----+
```